# How to install PHP 7 on Oracle Linux?

Tags: linux, installation, yum, oracle, php7

I have Oracle Linux 7.7 instance on Oracle cloud.
I want to install PHP 7.2 on it.
Previously I have installed PHP 7 on different Linux flavors but I could not find proper documentation, tutorial or how to guide for Oracle Linux.

I have installed PHP 7.2 using following command `sudo yum install rh-php72` but when I run

`php --version` it is not working.

Has someone installed php 7 on Oracle Linux on cloud?

I have following repos enabled

```
ol7_UEKR5/x86_64
ol7_addons/x86_64
ol7_developer/x86_64
ol7_developer_EPEL/x86_64
ol7_ksplice            
ol7_latest/x86_64
ol7_optional_latest/x86_64
ol7_software_collections/x86_64
```

Can you please tell me a reference or give steps to install PHP 7
Thanks in advance.

Comment: php is installed in `/opt/rh/rh-php72/root/usr/bin/php --version`  and it runs if I give full path.

Comment: You installed a Software Collection. Do you know [how to use Software Collections](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/docs/)?

Comment: No  I don't know, I am checking the link you have shared. Thanks.

Comment: That's great Michael, I ran `scl enable rh-php72 bash` and it is working :-)

Comment: It works only as cli not working in Apache.